# Drupal Addressfield in multistep webform is not working when we go on previous step

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-webform

I am working in Drupal with webform and addressfield module. I have created a multi-step webform using pagebreak functionality. In this form, I am using multiple address field. When I go to form first time, all address fields work properly and I can move on step by step but if I try to go back to previous step then no address field works. Its like multi-step form does not compatible with multiple address field. Can anyone please help me out or please provide me any patch regarding this issue.

Thanks,

Vishnu

Note: I have asked same question on http://drupal.stackexchange.com  but I did not get any answer. Please help me here or https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/207504/multiple-addressfield-in-multistep-webform-is-not-working-properly